# Flutter position row at bottom of screen inside a SingleChildScrollView?

Tags: flutter

I have a screen with a graph and some buttons and then some nav buttons...
in portrait, everything fits on the screen, but I want the nav buttons to be at the bottom of the screen, and the graph to be at the top of the screen

in landscape-phone, there's not enough room...

So I put the whole thing into a `SingleChildScrollView(child:column(child: [stuff, navbuttons])`, but that resulted in everything being close together and centered.

I tried `SingleChildScrollView(child:column(child: [stuff, Spacer, navbuttons])`, but that makes a *RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded* error.

What's the way to make a "SpacerBigEnough" class?

Comment: Stuff and nav button wrap with expanded

Comment: If you put expanded into a SingleChildScrollView, it detonates as the pieces try to expand to infinity...

Comment: If you want some fixed spacing use: `SizedBox(height: 100)` as the "Spacer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've accomplished similar UI by using a `CustomScrollView`, like so:

```
    CustomScrollView(
     slivers: <Widget>[
       SliverToBoxAdapter(
         child: Column(
           children: [stuff],
         ),
       ),
       SliverFillRemaining(
         hasScrollBody: false,
         child: Align(
           alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
           child: navbuttons,
         ),
       )
     ],
   )
```